# Why is DrawReversibleFrame so slow?

Tags: .net, winforms, draw

Why is ControlPaint.DrawReversibleFrame so slow?  I use it to draw a dashed frame around objects that are being resized or dragged around in my program. You can see that the redrawing lags quite a bit as the mouse is moved around.  In the MouseMove event, I use DrawReversibleFrame to draw the frame, so maybe that's my problem because it's redrawing too much. The funny thing is that while using my program under remote desktop, there is no problem and it redraws quite a bit faster and there is no lag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have just noticed that this only occurrs when Aero is used.  It works perfectly fine when I use any other desktop theme that is not using Aero.